# Does there exist some sort of classification of subvarieties of $\mathfrak{N}_2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, universal-algebra, nilpotent-groups

> Does there exist some sort of classification of subvarieties of $\mathfrak{N}_2$? Here $\mathfrak{N}_2$ stands for the variety of nilpotent groups of class $2$ (defined by the identity $[[x, y], z]$).

As we know that any variety is an intersection of a Burnside variety and a commutator variety (a variety in which all relatively free groups are torsion-free), it is sufficient to find all commutator subvarieties of $\mathfrak{N}_2$. Among them there are the variety of all abelian groups (defined by $[x, y]$ ). However, there definitely should be something else...

Comment: There is a geometric classification in low dimensions, i.e., up to $n\le 8$, see [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.04449) for references (including my own :) ).

Comment: I may be confused, but while the abelian groups are clearly a subvariety, I would think the 2-Engel groups aren't? '$[[x,y],z]$ is the identity for all $x,y,z$' is stronger than '$[[x,y],y]$ is the identity for all $x,y$' so there should be 2-Engel groups that aren't 2-nilpotent (and the groupprops wiki seems to agree; https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/2-Engel_group )

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: You are not confused; $\mathfrak{E}_2$ contains $\mathfrak{N}_2$, not the other way around.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the full classification exists. It can be deduced from the classification of subvarieties of $\mathfrak{N}_3$ given in:

1. Bjarni Jónsson, *Varieties of groups of nilpotency three*, Notices Amer. Math. Soc. **13** (1966), 488.
2. V.N. Remeslennikov, *Two remarks on 3-step nilpotent groups*, Algebra i Logika (1965) no. 2, 59--65, MR **31**:4838.

The first is an abstract, and has a typo (a $[y,x,z]$ should be $[y,x,x]$); the second contains the following classification:

> **Theorem.** Every subvariety of $\mathfrak{N}_3$ corresponds to a $4$-tuple of nonnegative integers $(m,n,p,q)$ satisfying:
>
> 1. $n|m/\gcd(2,m)$,
> 2. $p|m$,
> 3. $q|p$,
> 4. $q|m/\gcd(6,m)$, and
> 5. $p|3q$;
>
> corresponding to the identities 
>   $$x^m = [x,y]^n = [x,y,z]^p = [x,y,y]^q = [x,y,z,w] = 1.$$

From this, by taking $p=q=1$, we get:

> **Corollary.** Every subvariety of $\mathfrak{N}_2$ may be defined by the identities
>   $$x^m=[x,y]^n=[x,y,z]=1$$
>   for unique nonnegative integers $n$ and $m$ satisfying $n|m/\gcd(2,m)$.

**Note:** Every group of nilpotency class at most two is $2$-Engel, but not every $2$-Engel group has nilpotency class at most two; the $2$-Engel groups are **not** a subvariety of $\mathfrak{N}_2$; the $2$-Engel groups are the groups whose $2$-generated subgroups are in $\mathfrak{N}_2$, which *contains* $\mathfrak{N}_2$.  (The original post, prior to editing, included an off-hand assertion that the variety of $2$-Engel groups would be realized as a subvariety of $\mathfrak{N}_2$, hence this comment...)